# android service check for new messages while app is running

Tags: android, service

I have an app that users can get messages but there is no way they no they have a message unless the app is currently open. They dont even no if they have a message if the app is in recent activity. What i want to do is when the user logs in it starts like a service or timer or something of that nature so it goes through a loop and keep checking the database for a message. Any suggestions please post code example, i am lost when it comes to stuff like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BroadCast Receiver and register it in Manifest.xml so that it will listen to your message(broadcast) when app is not running also
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html